# Better option to alter Azure cosmos db documents in PROD

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Need to alter around 10,000 Azure cosmos db documents by adding new property as one time activity on PROD, for this kind of scenario Bulk support in the .NET SDK v3 (OR)  Cosmos DB Bulk Executor (OR)  better off with a loop which replace documents one-by-one, which one to be considered?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with Azure Functions that have CosmosDB trigger (with flag StartFromBeginning=true). That will send change feed for all of your documents into your Azure Function.

Now, i'd have a filter that checks if the document have that property or not. If it doesn't, i'd update it and if it does i'd do nothing. this second case is needed because change feed will trigger your Azure Function not only for first time but also after you update it.

Comment: But the question is about how to alter (or) update the document? whether it should be one by one fashion or using bulk options?

Comment: @191180rk well, i guess that's up to you. if you want it to be done faster (but with the price of higher provisioned throughput needed) - you go with bulk. if you don't care how fast is it being done but you want to have it with a lower throughput - don't go  with bulk. ref: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/

Comment: @ deezg Also thought of using azure function with sql query like select * from c where NOT IS_DEFINED(c.newproperty) to update the records rather than relying on change feed as my requirement is one time activity & has nothing to do with every single change happening on every documents. Your thoughts?

Comment: well, for that you don't need any azure function. you could very well go with console application on your machine. the problem i see with going with query like that is you have to handle batching yourself (if not going with batch/bulk option). with azure functions & change feed you get a straightforward mechanism that's proven to work in a few lines of code. i'm not saying you can't do it, i just express my preferences because i think going with functions and change feed combined is the most straightforward option.

Comment: @ deezg, your points taken but I'm not confident of using change feed as I have this doubt letz say, 100 changes happened on a document in its life cycle, how many entries available on change feed  for that document whether it is 100 or single entry ? Suppose if change feed  have 100 entries, function will be triggered for 100 time unnecessarily (provided StartFromBeginning=true set on azure cosmos binding) & function has to do unnecessary filter checks for another 99times whether the document have that new property or not which doesn't seems like efficient way to deal. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @191180rk you're right about that. again, i'm not saying its the only solution nor that its even the best one. it definitely depends on your database. for example, you haven't mentioned if you're making those changes on all documents in a container or is it just a small fraction. that's also something to factor in. although running a function that, in turn, does nothing (filter applied) is pretty low cost...anyways, you have a point and your proposal is also a perfectly valid one.

Comment: Thanks @deezg. FYI, I'm going make changes on all the documents(~10,000 count) of particular collection which is in the production for last 1 year. Obviously changes made on the target documents all these time business should be of some decent number and definitely it will be of more than once.

Comment: Please refrain from having a discussion in comments. Much better to do this in [chat].

Comment: Here's an approach to consider to keep it simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185738/2411713